# Show that $\mathbb{Z}[x] \to \mathbb{Z}[x]/(2) \times \mathbb{Z}[x]/(x)$ is not surjective.

Tags: abstract-algebra

In Aluffi's book it says that $\mathbb{Z}[x] \to \mathbb{Z}[x]/(2) \times \mathbb{Z}[x]/(x)$ is not surjective. To prove that I need to know how that means at all! Why it is not surjective if for any polynomial $q(x)$ we can write $(q(x)+2n_1, q(x)+n_2x)$?

Comment: How is the map defined?

Comment: @Servaes, natural projection. It's an example to a theorem for $\phi$ a natural projection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The product on the right hand side is generated by $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$. So the map is surjective if and only if these are in the image of the map, i.e. if there exist polynomials $f,g\in\Bbb{Z}[x]$ such that
$$f\ \longmapsto\ (1,0)\qquad\text{ and }\qquad g\ \longmapsto\ (0,1).$$
Show that this is impossible.

Comment: How are the typical/general elements of $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(2)$ and $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x)$?

Comment: They are polynomials with integer coefficients mod $2$, and simply integers.

Comment: I could understand now their meanings but still don't understand the meaning for surjection esp because the rhs is 'double'-element. To try to show that (first) it is surjective (then fail), so we try to find a polynomial such that *simultaneously* (??) is an integer *and* a polynomial with integer coefficients mod 2? But it is not intersection it is product.

Comment: I've expanded my hint into a sketch of an answer.

Comment: *"Which elements of Z[x] map to (1,0)"* : so is this a counterexample? : for any polynomial q(x) in Z[x], 2q(x)+1 is the only element of Z[x] such that it is 1 in Z[x]/(2) but 2q(x)+1 is never 0 in Z[x]/(x); am I right?

Comment: You are absolutely right, though your phrasing is a bit off; rather, every polynomial in $\Bbb{Z}[x]$ that maps to $1$ in $\Bbb{Z}[x]/(2)$ is of the form $2q(x)+1$ for some polynomial $q(x)\in\Bbb{Z}[x]$.

Comment: Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @72D The key idea is that the map is surjective iff the ideals are comaximal - see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\ R \to R/I \times R/J $ surjective $\Rightarrow I + J = 1$

since $\,r\to (1,0)\,\Rightarrow\, 1 = (1\!-\!r) + r\in I + J$